# Ошибка сетевого адаптера. Код 32

Tags: windows

После перезагрузки ноутбука WiFI адаптер Realtek стал выводить ошибку: "Драйвер для этого устройства был отключен". Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте откат. Если не поможет - подключитесь к Инету по кабелю, удалите WiFi-адаптер (но убедитесь, что под рукой есть драйвер от производителя ноута), на предложение удалить также и драйвер согласитесь. Ребут. Повторять, пока адаптер не будет определяться как устройство без драйвера, или пока не будет установлен драйвер от M$. После чего обновите драйвер через MSUpdate.